# Error when attempting to read Parquet in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am using Python Spark 2.4.3

I read the CSV and make a dataframe from it and write it to Parquet just fine. The 3rd line is what breaks.

```
df = spark.read.csv("file.csv", header=True)
df.write.parquet("result_parquet")
parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("result_parquet")
```

I am getting this:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1312.parquet.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
```

What am I doing wrong? I got the line straight from the Spark documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#loading-data-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I was using Java 11 (not supported fully by Spark). I uninstalled and Installed Java 8 and now it works